# Adding Poll to Blog Content Type

Tags: 7, polls

I'm using D7, and I've created the Content Type 'Poll'. That said, I want to add a specific Poll I've created to a published Blog Entry. Is this possible? I thought about creating a poll block, but this would just publish the same poll on all of my Blog Entries? I also can't seem to add a specific Poll field to my Content Type 'Blog'...

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module

Then in your blogs content type, add a new field

- Name: [what ever you like] I named mine aaaa
- Type: entity reference
- Widget: auto complete.
- Then on the settings page for Target Bundle select poll.

Then edit your block, and in entity reference field (aaaa), type your poll name and save changes.

---

In [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), create a block view of poll.

Under Advanced, RELATIONSHIPS add Entity Reference: Referec**ing** entity NOT referenc**ed**.

[image]

**Checkmark require this relationship**.

[image]

Then add a CONTEXTUAL FILTER of Content: Nid

For Relationship, select your referecing

Provide default value, Content ID from URL.

[image]

Note: your view preview will be blank, but it will show up when you view the blog.

Lastly, in blocks, assign your view block to a region.

Now this will automatically show the poll that you reference in your blog.